Additional License required for using Image Analysis tagging in Sitecore Content Hub?
Does the Image Analysis feature require an Additional License in Sitecore Content Hub? I have been trying to add Image Analysis for a few Assets by enabling the Trigger vision boolean in the Asset Type Taxonomy. But the Assets were not tagged and on checking in the background process I encountered the error as 

Please add errors as text for SEO reasons.

Have you checked: https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/content-user-manual--image-analysis.html#enable-the-vision-service. Under the section enable the vision service?

To resolve the issue, you need to enable the vision service. Please refer to the documentation at https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/content-user-manual--image-analysis.html.
Additionally, you can find more information on

Applying image analysis to a single asset
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/content-user-manual--image-analysis.html#apply-image-analysis-to-a-single-asset

Using the "Edit in Table" feature
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/content-user-manual--image-analysis.html#apply-image-analysis-using-edit-in-table

Through mass editing
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/content-user-manual--image-analysis.html#apply-image-analysis-using-mass-edit


Hope this helps!
